# Drawing a electrical component

Tags: components, datasheet, drawing

I would like to know, how could I draw a component picture like datasheet? I have attached one picture also. I want to draw the same component as the attached picture. Should I use Autocad electrical or Inkspace or any other software? 
Thanks

[image: datasheet]

Comment: The best tool is the one you have and know how to use. I could draw this in Excel pretty quick using pixel values for mm, but then who cares. It's what you want to do with it that also counts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add on to what Peter said, also from the Autodesk family is Autodesk Fusion 360. It's a 3d modeling program but you can generate 2D drawings from it. They have a free trial as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make a mechanical drawing, as you have shown, any mechanical drafting program, including AutoCad, should be fine.

I haven't used AutoCad Electrical, but I'd guess that it is intended more for schematics and wiring diagrams, than for mechanical drawings.